# the name object ' ' is not valid mybatis

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, mybatis

My problem is when I execute the query, the server return :

```
### SQL: SELECT DISTINCT       a.Codigo, a.Descripcion, a.TipoIva, a.Etiqueta1, a.Etiqueta2, a.Etiqueta3, a.Precio, a.Precio2, a.Precio3, a.Precio4,   a.Familia, a.CodigoExterno, a.LoteCompra , a.BloqueadoVenta, a.BloqueadoCompra , a.UltProveedor, a.UnidadesCompra,   a.PrecioMedio, a.FechaUltimaVenta, a.PrecioCompra  FROM Gv_Productos a    WHERE a.Codigo = ?
### Cause: java.sql.SQLException: El nombre de objeto 'Gv_Productos' no es válido. ; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: El nombre de objeto 

'Gv_Productos' no es válido. 
........ 
.... 
.....
...
```

but this query is great because I execute in 'heidi' and sql server and run....
the name of table is : dbo.Gv_Productos , dbo is a schema

[image]
any solution ?

Comment: Did you try `FROM Gv_Productos AS a ` ?

Comment: yes.. not working... 
.... a.FechaUltimaVenta, a.PrecioCompra      FROM Gv_Productos AS a .....

Comment: did you try from dbo.Gv_Productos?

Comment: the BBDD have a schema (dbo.gv_productos), could be so

Answer (score 0):

the solution is very easy...

```
SELECT * FROM nameBBDD.<Schema>.<Table>
```

in my case bbdd.dbo.Gv_Productos

thanks